# A web app that gets queries and displays them live

Tags: logs, dashboard, tracking

Is there a web app that:

1. Gets a query from a third party that could be anything, for example `?foo=bar&some=thing`.
2. Displays to the owner a dashboard of all the queries it got in the last X minutes (optional: hopefully after dividing the query entries into a nice table, assuming the names like `foo` and `some` are always the same).

?

Comment: Open a terminal to your Unix webserver, and issue this command: `tail -100f /var/log/apache/access_log` . The filename can be different, and you can augment the command to your needs (e.g. filter only requests with http status 200, OK.

Comment: I see your point, but I've asked for a web app. Also keep in mind access_log is a giant file that's not easy to work with on a frequent level.

Comment: You can wrap this shell command as a cgi script. Maybe there are log-viewer apache modules, or nginx modules that do the same thing,  just a bit differently.